# operating on a dataset with 125,497,040 records

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to run [add_datepart()](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/af4773bbba8fa535d8e9e0af0879a12acc174046/old/fastai/structured.py#L76) which converts a df column from a datetime64 to many columns in place

Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'Day', 'Dayofweek', 'Dayofyear','Ismonthend', 'Ismonthstart', 'Isquarterend', 'Isquarterstart', 'Isyearend', 'Isyearstart' . etc

I'm using is [Grocery Sales dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/favorita-grocery-sales-forecasting/data). Total dates i believe in that are 125497040. What should I do to run this operation?

Every time I run this piece of code. The kernel dies(out of memory which is 17.2 GB RAM)

So I tried breaking down this data frame in smaller parts and then running `add_datepart` but still the same result

I wrote this code

```
def add_datepart_large(temp_df, size):
    list_df = [temp_df[i:i+size] for i in range(0,temp_df.shape[0],size)]
    for i in range(len(list_df)): add_datepart(list_df[i], 'date')
    return pd.concat(list_df)

final_df = add_datepart_large(df_all, 100000)
```

If after running this code, the kernel dies. What's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong... It needs more memory and you can't provide it ... Hence OOM... Split the data into chunks and then do

Comment: @Aditya I have done exactly same. The code I wrote divides it into 100000. Should I split it further?

Comment: Added some details on how to train / test data once you have processed it.

Comment: I don't think so... Because you are still saving them all at once.. you need to load them on fly and process them

Comment: @Aditya can you be more specific. Contribute an answer. What I'm doing and what should be done. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For 127 million rows, it is better to perform data prep on DB. It will be a select + insert query and will not require whole data to be loaded in memory.

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS 'year', MONTH(date) AS 'month'
 FROM data
```

Edit : Once you start training / validation, even then it would be better to load few batches from DB (at a time). Most frameworks support this.

Foe example : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/107

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say how to fix this is Pandas, without having to likely restructure your approach to the problem (due to the size of your data).

Have a look at the [python datatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable) package, which is like a database running in memory and is much more performant for larger dataframes, where Pandas might start to crash. It consumes less memory and internally works like a database.

I should additionally mention [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/), which is a distributed version of Pandas that can perhaps cope better than Pandas itself with larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions:

It looks like your function calls `add_datepart` on each *row* in data frame individually, which will introduce a lot of overhead. Instead you could try splitting `df_all` into chunks (something like `tmp_dfs = [df_all.iloc[i:i+size] for i in range(...)])`, then applying `add_datepart` to each *chunk*, and then concatenating the chunks back together. That would at least create less overhead, although 130 M rows is pretty large for Pandas running on a personal machine.

Dask is a library that provides a [more-or-less drop-in replacement for Pandas data frames](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) and is designed to work with very large data sets. I haven't tested it with your data set, but it could be as simple as

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df_all = dd.read_csv(...) # Whatever arguments you used for pd.read_csv
add_datepart(df_all)
```

Dask is actually just providing a wrapper around regular Pandas data frames, so if you ever get to a situation that Dask doesn’t handle automatically you can always fall back on [`map_partitions`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions).

Comment: I did same. Break into chunks and loop. But I still get that kernel died errors and runs out of memory. Check my code

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan what I mean is that this line in your code: `for i in range(len(list_df)): add_datepart(list_df[i], 'date')` is processing each chunk one row at a time; instead it might be better to process the whole chunk at once. Possibly just `add_datepart(list_df)`.

Comment: yaa in that case kernel dies

Answer (score 0):

- Read your data from disk by chunk in loop

> for chunk in pd.read_csv(..., chunksize=10^6)

- Apply your function to DataFrame
- Store your DataFrame with "a" mode

> chunk.to_csv(..., mode="a")

Comment: I'm saving data to feather format. Saving it /tmp/ and then reading that